# Did "Riley" help the robbers rob the Connors' house?

Tags: terminator-series, the-sarah-connor-chronicles

In Terminator: The Sarah Connor Chronicles season 2 Episode 7 **"Brothers of Nablus"** the Connors find they have been robbed (at the endig of the episode we can see it's 4 guys). They took their money, credit cards, diamonds, Id's and even food. When Sarah asks John what happened to the security system he put on, Cameron replies that Riley climbed the window of John's room (sneak) and she forgot to turn on the security system.

So did Riley purposely turn off the security system in the Connors' house to make it easy for robbers to rob the house? Was this Jesse's plan?